# Defining operators to std library classes

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I am a windows 7 user using Visual Studio Express 2012. The used compiler is the compiler coming with the program. The specific problem that I have is that initializer_list is not yet supported for vectors for this version of Visual Studio. Also I seem to have problems using the initializer_list class. I am not sure if this is due to my own incapability or not, but the fact remains that I cannot use initializer_list to vector.

However, I would like to have something with the same syntax as an intializer_list even if the implementation. However, since the main reason that I write to SO is Learning this is not the question. I figure that if it is possible to create operators to std classes it would be possible to define an operator working like initializer_list for a vector, so the question is then:

**Is it possible to define an opperator to a std library class and if so, how can I do it?**

What I have tried is to create an example creating a vector of length 1:

```
#include<iostream> //Used for later debugging
#include<vector>
#include<string> // Used later

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator {} (T y){
std::vector<T> out;
out.push_back(y);
return out;
};

int main(){
std::vector<int> v = {1};
}
```

This does not work at all. In fact, this does not even compile. A working example would be appreciated, but a minimal example with an operator doing anything with a vector would be enough. I figure that my main problem is to define an operator to an already existing class is the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And don't forget. You cannot define a new operator to be overloaded. Just a bunch of them can be overloaded.

First google result brought up: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html

Overloaded can be:

```
    +       -       *       /       %       ^       &       |
    ~       !       ,       =              =
    ++      --      <<      >>      ==      !=      &&      ||
    +=      -=      /=      %=      ^=      & =     |=      *=
    <<=     >>=     [ ]     ( )     ->      ->*     new     delete
    new[]   delete[]
```

You cannot overload:

```
    ?       .*
```

And you cannot define a new operator, and especially ***not*** the { } operator.

Comment: Ok I see. This is sad for me then, but I guess that it is an extremely good reason for this. It makes sense of course.

Comment: Ok since it is not possible to create an operator as in the question I guess that I will need to accept this answer and post a more specific question. Thank you anyway.